# Filter array of objects based on other array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filtering

I'm trying to filter out the corresponding font-colors from the field array in the object optionData:

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "color",
            "id": "font-color",
            "value": "#222",
            "target": "font",
            "dependency": []
        },
        {
            "type": "color",
            "id": "font-color",
            "value": "#f00",
            "target": "font",
            "dependency": []
        }
    ],
    "textposition": {
        "left": "12",
        "top": "10"
    },
    "textsubtitle": "Kleur",
    "additionalcosts": "4,99"
}
```

I have a dependency array where I keep the dependencies. In this case it consists only of font-colors and 2 values; #fff and #222. Therefore I want to filter out the #222.

Depencies:

```
[
  {
    "field": "font-color",
    "value": "#fff"
  },
  {
    "field": "font-color",
    "value": "#222"
  }
]
```

```
const optionData = {"fields":[{"type":"color","id":"font-color","value":"#222","target":"font","dependency":[]},{"type":"color","id":"font-color","value":"#f00","target":"font","dependency":[]}],"textposition":{"left":"12","top":"10"},"textsubtitle":"Kleur","additionalcosts":"4,99"};

console.log(optionData, 'optionData');

const dependency = [{"field":"font-color","value":"#fff"},{"field":"font-color","value":"#222"}];

console.log(dependency, 'dependency');

let filtered = optionData['fields'].filter(field => {
  console.log(field, 'field');
  return dependency.filter(dependency => {
    console.log(dependency, 'dependency')
    return dependency['field'] !== field['id'] && dependency['value'] !== field['value'];
  })
})

console.log(filtered, 'filtered');
```

Comment: Is your expected output just the field objects that match the dependencies, or do you want the _whole options object returned_ with the `fields` array only containing those matching the dependencies.

Comment: I'd like to return the whole options object in the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
const optionData = {
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "font-color",
      "value": "#222",
      "target": "font",
      "dependency": []
    },
    {
      "type": "color",
      "id": "font-color",
      "value": "#f00",
      "target": "font",
      "dependency": []
    }
  ],
  "textposition": {
    "left": "12",
    "top": "10"
  },
  "textsubtitle": "Kleur",
  "additionalcosts": "4,99"
};

const dependency = [
  {"field": "font-color", "value": "#fff"},
  {"field": "font-color", "value": "#222"}
];

let filtered = optionData['fields'].filter(field => {
  return !dependency.some(dependency => {
    return dependency['field'] === field['id'] && dependency['value'] === field['value'];
  });
});

console.log(filtered);
```

The code uses the filter method to iterate over the optionData['fields'] array and keep only the objects that satisfy the filtering condition. The condition is implemented using the some method on the dependency array. It checks if there is at least one object in dependency that matches both the field and value of the current object in optionData['fields']. The ! operator negates the result so that only objects that do not have a matching dependency are kept.

In the provided example, the filtered array will contain only the object with value: "#f00" since it does not match any of the dependencies in the dependency array

Answer (score 1):

`filter` uses a boolean (the result of a condition) to determine whether an element should be filtered or not, however your inner `filter` returns a new array so it's not really suitable.

There is another array method that you can use that *does* return a boolean: [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). For each iterated field you can check to see if `some` of the corresponding entries in the dependencies array are a match. If there is a match the method immediately breaks so that the whole dependency array doesn't have to be iterated over.

```js
const options={fields:[{type:"color",id:"font-color",value:"#222",target:"font",dependency:[]},{type:"color",id:"font-color",value:"#f00",target:"font",dependency:[]}],textposition:{left:"12",top:"10"},textsubtitle:"Kleur",additionalcosts:"4,99"},dependencies=[{field:"font-color",value:"#fff"},{field:"font-color",value:"#222"}];

function filterDependencies(options, dependencies) {
  
  // Return a new object from (spreading out) the
  // old object, and creating a new fields array by
  // filtering out any fields that are in the dependecies
  // array
  return {
    ...options,
    fields: options.fields.filter(field => {

      // For each iterate field if `some` (ie any) of the
      // corresponding dependency array fields are a match
      // If there is a match return false, otherwise true.
      // Use that boolean as your `filter` condition
      return !dependencies.some(q => {
        return (
          q.field === field.id
          && q.value === field.value
        );
      });

    })
  }
}

console.log(filterDependencies(options, dependencies));
```

Additional documentation

- [Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)